# MediaPlayer with Custom MediaStreamSource UWP Chunk

Tags: c#, http, uwp, streaming, media

I had a mediasource getting an audio chunk from a file in a HttpRequest and setting the sample in SampleRequested to the MediaElement which was working, now I am doing the same thing with MediaPlayer, NO Media element and no sound rendering.

Is there a trick with using MediaPlayer?

Thanks

```
TimeSpan sampleDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
MediaPlayer player = null;
MediaSource src = null;
MediaStreamSource ss = null;

string url = null;
long receivedBytes = 0;

private const uint SAMPLE_RATE = 48000; // Max Supported
private const uint CHANNEL_COUNT = 6;
private const uint BIT_RATE = 256;
private const long CHUNK_SAMPLE_SIZE = 249999;

public Test(string url)
{
    this.url = url;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.AutoPlay = false;

    var encodingProps = AudioEncodingProperties.CreateAacAdts(SAMPLE_RATE,CHANNEL_COUNT, BIT_RATE);
    if (encodingProps == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var audioStreamDescriptor = new AudioStreamDescriptor(encodingProps);
    if (audioStreamDescriptor == null)
    {
        encodingProps = null;
        return;
    }

    ss = null;
    ss = new MediaStreamSource(audioStreamDescriptor);
    if (ss == null)
    {
        encodingProps = null;
        audioStreamDescriptor = null;
        return;
    }
    ss.CanSeek = true;
    ss.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

    var avgSeconds = (encodingProps.ChannelCount * 16 / 8) *    encodingProps.SampleRate;
    sampleDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CHUNK_SAMPLE_SIZE / avgSeconds);

    ss.Starting += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Request.SetActualStartPosition(sampleDuration);
    };

    player.MediaFailed += (s, e) =>
    {
        int i = 0;
    };

    ss.SampleRequested += SampleRequested;

    player.CommandManager.IsEnabled = false;
    player.RealTimePlayback = true;
    src = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(ss);
    player.Source = src;

 }

private async void SampleRequested(object sender,   MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral(); ;

    var sample = FileManager.GetInstance().RequestHostFileStreamChunk(url, CommonData.HOST_CONNECTION_ID.E_ONEDRIVE, receivedBytes, CHUNK_SAMPLE_SIZE);

    if (sample != null)
    {
        sample.Position = 0;
    //  Stream transcoded = AVTranscoder.GetInstance().GetTranscodedAsStream(sample).Result;

        MediaStreamSample streamSample = await MediaStreamSample.CreateFromStreamAsync(sample.AsInputtStream(), (uint)sample.Length, player.PlaybackSession.Position);
        if (streamSample != null)
        {
            var avgSeconds = (1 * 16 / 8) * SAMPLE_RATE + sample.Length;
            sampleDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CHUNK_SAMPLE_SIZE / avgSeconds);
            streamSample.Duration = sampleDuration;
            player.PlaybackSession.Position += streamSample.Duration;
            args.Request.Sample = streamSample;

            receivedBytes += sample.Length;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    deferral.Complete();
}

public void Start()
{
    player.Play();
}
```

Comment: What's the FileManager? Please share a [mcve] with us. And a url for me to test.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT thanks for the reply, it durns out it was a minor bug due to my stupidity, I was indexing a file ID of a non mp3 format so there was no playback, it is working now I just need to tweak playback position and sample durations for the player on a per sample basis. Will also need to get the encoder working to make the player format agnostic, can the MediaTranscoder transcode byte samples or does it need a whole file, do you know? Thanks

Comment: MediaTranscoder has prepare file/mediastream/stream transcode method. It should could transcode byte samples. See MSDN source: [MediaTranscoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207080)

Comment: @Xavier Xie - MSFT thanks for that, I had been using PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync however I was getting a bad PrepareTranscodeResult when feeding it a http content chunk about 0.4 mb long. Are there any known issues with data sizes for the transcoder to work? Thanks again